# Can´t edit sourcecode in VS Texteditor when resharper is running

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper, stylecop

For some time I use Resharper in Visual Studio 12, but since a few days I have a problem. If Resharper running, I can not type anything in the source code editor in Visual Studio.

I'm using the version 8.2.0.2160 
and StyleCop version 4.7.49.0

All settings I have completely reset. I have also deleted the settings files. I have also uninstalled Resharper and StyleCop and reinstalled.

Nothing helps! The strange thing is, that I (except C# and xaml) can probably edit in other files. 
Or when I restart Visual Studio and there investing a new project. Then everything works properly.

I do not know how to fix the problem. What could I even check what I could try?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Resharper's support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a shredded cache in **PersistentCache** directory of resharper. When I deleted the directory, resharper had re-creates it and everything worked perfectly again!

Answer (score 1):

go to the following location:

```
%AppData%\..\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches\
```

Delete the desired solution cache. I have not sufficient reputation to comment that's why posting as answer, could be helpful for someone to locate the directory of solution cache.

Comment: Many Thanks! Your post makes it easier to find the right directory :-)