# Cannot edit files after latest Resharper update

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

Just ran the latest nuget package to update the Resharper C# files to 8.2

Now I am unable to edit any files in Visual Studio 12.
Is anyone else experiencing this?

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Resolved..  Deleting the 'PersistentCaches' folders from 'C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches\_ReSharper.[solutionfile].[id]'\  forced resharper to rebuild this folder and I'm able to edit again.

Comment: I am not having any problems. but please post this as solution, it may be helpful to  someone with the same problem .

Comment: @bansi,  I will, but currently don't have enough rep to answer my own question for 8 hours..

Comment: Looks like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/23389661/411428

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution suggested by OP.

You can fix this by deleting the solution cache. In Windows 8 the solution cache is normally stored at `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches\_ReSharper.[SolutionName].[id]`. Please use appropriate value `username`, `SolutionName` and `id`.

Comment: For those lazy like me: ``%Appdata%\..\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches\``

Comment: `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Transient\ReSharperPlatformVs15\v09_2918fbb3\SolutionCaches\_YourSolution.-timestamp\`